# On the compactness of [0,1].

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

Is there a constructive proof of the compactness of $[0,1]$ with Euclidean topology? Constructive means given $U$ a open cover, shows a proof that define a strategy to find the finite open cover. An example of what I meant is given by [Lebesgue number lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue%27s_number_lemma). This is a "constructive" proof that output a Lebesgue number(not necessarily the best).  In other words to extend the problem given a open cover of a compact space is there a general algorithm(not optimal, just general) to provide a finite subcover. My suspect is not. But maybe there are scenarios where is possible. Thanks

Comment: Here is a scenario where it can be done https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4154900/897162

Comment: The exercise you post does not consider open cover compactness(H-B)definition and do not talk about compactness of [0,1] . Is just a second year standard exercise. Probably I am missing something or there is a miss understanding

Comment: In what form is your open cover given? And what operations do you allow for your algorithm? I suspect that for any reasonable answer to these questions, one can give an example of an open cover of a compact space for which you cannot construct a finite subcover. But I'd love to be proven wrong.

Comment: Let first consider the general case as in the Lebesgue number lemma of a generic open cover U and find a constructive proof of the compactness of [0-1] . The question about the algorithm is less precise, is just a computational point of view, I modify it is not my main interest. It would be great if a constructive proof exist. Thanks p.s what I wanted to notice is that constructive proof gives you (in small) a possible computational strategy if you of course define correctly the operations on your Turing machine with infinite memory

Comment: The proof of Lebesgue number lemma not only requires (1) the choice of finite subcover, but also (2) calculation of $d(x,C)$ and (3) findining a minimum of a function. None of these can be done in constructive way in general. Unless you have some extended notion of "constructive".

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constructive_proof. I just want to create a logic way to find that directly. That is the best I can do to make me clear. I am sorry if it is still unclear

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is well-known that there is no way to constructively prove the compactness of $[0, 1]$. Indeed, it is consistent with constructive mathematics that there exists a uniformly continuous function $f : [0, 1] \to (0, \infty)$ such that $\inf_{x \in [0, 1]} f(x) = 0$; this clearly contradicts compactness, as expounded upon in [this paper](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/pacific-journal-of-mathematics/volume-111/issue-2/A-uniformly-continuous-function-on-01-that-is-everywhere-different/pjm/1102710574.pdf). However, it is fairly common for constructive mathematicians to assume certain topologically inspired axioms which entail the compactness of $[0, 1]$ such as bar induction.

Comment: Thanks a lot. The paper is very interesting . I'll probably spend the next 2 hours reading it.